# Using JQuery to create animation frames from PSD layers

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, frames, psd

I have a PSD file with a bunch of layers that are frames for an animation. How can I create an animation from this using JQuery/JavaScript?

Will I have to save each layer as a separate image,  is there a way to have the one image with multiple layers animated? To clarify, I don't want the actual image to move, I just want different layers to be displayed as if they were frames of an animation. What's the standard way this is done with JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: Individual images per frame + javacsript timer to my knowledge. Why not convert the frames to gif? I know that's not your question. Just wondering.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates the javascript timer + individual images approach.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZVFu8/2/

The basic idea is to create an array with the names of your images.

```
var img_name_arr = [];
var img_name_root = "anim-";
var img_name_ext = ".gif";
var num_images = 12;

// init arr of img names assuming frames are named [root]+i+[extension]
for (i = 0; i<=num_images; i++) {
    img_name_arr.push(img_name_root + i + img_name_ext);
}
```

For the animation, use setInterval(). In javascript, an interval executes periodically. You specify the code to execute and the interval at which the code should be run (in milliseconds).

Every time your interval is called, you can display a new image by setting the "src" attribute of the image tag to the next index in the image_name array.

```
// Create an interval, and save a handle to the interval so it can be stopped later
anim_interval = setInterval(function() {
    $("#player").attr("src", s + img_name_arr[(anim_frame++ % num_images)+1] );
}, frame_interval);
```

Depending on how long your animation is and how large each image file is, it might be necessary to optimize this by pre-loading these images. Before the animation starts, you could create an img tag for each image and hide it. Then, instead of altering the "src" attribute to change the image, you would actually hide the current image and un-hide the next image in the previous image's place.

Here is the full code if you wish to run this locally:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="anim_control" href="">Start</a>
<img id="player" src="" />


<script>
var s = "http://" + atob("YmVucmlkb3V0LmNvbQ==") + "/";
var img_name_arr = [];
var img_name_root = "anim-";
var img_name_ext = ".gif";
var num_images = 12;

var framerate = 1; // Desired frames per second
var frame_interval = 1000/framerate;


$(function(){
    // Document is ready
    // init arr of img names
    for (i = 0; i <= num_images; i++) {
        img_name_arr.push(img_name_root + i + img_name_ext);
    }


    var anim_interval = null;
    var playing = false;
    var anim_frame = 0;

    // Define an interval that will execute every [frame_interval] milliseconds
    $("#anim_control").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (playing == true) {
            playing = false;
            $(this).html("Start");
            clearInterval(anim_interval);
        } else {
            playing = true;
            $(this).html("Stop");
            anim_interval = setInterval(function() {
                //console.log(s + img_name_arr[(anim_frame++ % num_images)+1]);
                $("#player").attr("src", s + img_name_arr[(anim_frame++ % num_images)+1] );
            }, frame_interval);
        }
    });
});
</script>

<style>
#player {
    width: 320px;
    height: 240px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>
```